# How to use XQuery to count the occurrences of all the elements and attributes in an XML file?

Tags: xml, xquery

Input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <books>
        <book id="6636551">
            <master_information>
                <book_xref>
                    <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">72771KAM3</xref>
                    <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US72771KAM36</xref>
                </book_xref>
            </master_information>
            <book_details>
                <price>24.95</price>
                <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
                <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
            </book_details>
        </book>
        <book id="119818569">
            <master_information>
                <book_xref>
                    <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UL5</xref>
                    <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UL50</xref>
                </book_xref>
            </master_information>
            <book_details>
                <price>19.25</price>
                <publish_date>2002-11-01</publish_date>
                <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
            </book_details>
        </book>
        <book id="119818568">
            <master_information>
                <book_xref>
                    <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UK7</xref>
                    <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UK77</xref>
                </book_xref>
            </master_information>
            <book_details>
                <price>5.95</price>
                <publish_date>2004-05-01</publish_date>
                <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society.</description>
            </book_details>
        </book>
        <book id="119818567">
            <master_information>
                <book_xref>
                    <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UJ0</xref>
                    <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UJ05</xref>
                </book_xref>
            </master_information>
            <book_details>
                <price>4.95</price>
                <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
                <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
            </book_details>
        </book>
    </books>
```

I was able to make a simple count function with a header (FYI - I'm new to Xquery)

```
let $x := string-join(('xref', count(//book//xref)), '&#58;')
return $x
```

I get the count with a header as expected

```
xref:8
```

I tried expanding that to work for all elements and attribute but it doesn't work. I put in $x for header which is obviously wrong - is there a function to grab the name of the element/attr that I can use. I couldn't find one.

```
for $x in //book
let $c := string-join(($x, count($x)), '&#58;')
return $x
```

I want the prefix header to be the "name of the element/attr" and then followed by a colon and the count of that element/attr. What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate your response.

P.S. I understand some might think this kind of stuff is easier to do in XSLT but I would like to stick with Xquery for all data queries as much as possible. I find Xquery easier to understand than XSLT because of its SQL like syntax structure which I'm already comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a variant of the solution from @wst, adapted to take advantage of XQuery 3.0 features:

```
declare function local:clarkName($name as xs:QName) { 
  "{"||namespace-uri-from-QName($name)||"}"||local-name-from-QName($name)
};

let $doc := document{<a><b/><b/><c xmlns="c.com"/></a>}
for $node in $doc//*
group by $name := node-name($node)
return local:clarkName($name) || ":" || count($node)
```

Output (depending on the serialization method, and in undefined order):

```
"{}b:2"
"{c.com}c:1"
"{}a:1"
```

Comment: the let $doc line looks for an external file on my system right? I tried to put in the file path but it didn't work. I generally load the XML file in BaseX GUI and then run the XQuery on it. What do I need to do to load the XML file in your code? Thanks!

Comment: Use the doc() function in the usual way.

Answer (score 4):

This is also easy to do in XQuery. The strategy is to get distinct values of the element names first, then query for their counts. The tricky part is doing that while preserving namespaces. Here is an example that builds element QName values into Clark notation strings first, then gets distinct values, then rebuilds the QName before querying via XPath.

```
let $doc := (: some document :)
let $names := distinct-values($doc//*/concat('{' , namespace-uri-from-QName(node-name(.)), '}', local-name(.)))
for $n in $names
let $ns := substring-after(substring-before($n, '}'), '{')
let $local-name := substring-after($n, '}')
let $qname := QName($ns, $local-name)
return concat($n, ':', count($doc//*[node-name(.) = $qname]))
```

This query could be easily modified to report on multiple documents or elements, but just note that as the number of elements increases, so will the time it takes to run the query.

Comment: You could also apply distinct-values() to the QNames directly: `let $names := distinct-values($doc//*/node-name())`, and then convert to Clark notation at display time: call `function local:clarkName($node) { "{"||namespace-uri($node)||"}"||local-name($node)}`